# Compiz ( or even compositing in general) is not starting up when I login. Solution?

Tags: unity, 12.04, compiz, compositing

Whenever I log into a desktop environment, it doesn't seem that compositing is starting. Unity 2D works fine, but when I go to Unity 3D Compiz doesn't start up. I have to type `compiz --replace &` in terminal every time I login. Another example is when I log into a Cinnamon session, theming support is suddenly gone (although this may be a separate issue). If it helps im using the latest (295.40) NVIDIA drivers.

EDIT:
I am having exactly the same issue in both cases, upgrading from 11.10 and with a clean installation, in 32 and 64 bits.

[Related post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/cant-get-compiz-to-work-in-ubuntu-11-10-a-938376/).

Answer (score 1):

Many people seem to have the same problem.

You will need to delete the compiz and compiz-1 directories in your home .config directory.

Compiz files are then re-generated when you re-boot and log in again.

It worked for me.

Comment: "/ i tried this but compiz is still not starting up.

Answer (score 1):

`sudoedit /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session`

try to check if everything is ok there (it opens you session config file). There should be this line:

`DefaultProvider-windowmanager=compiz`

Also make sure that your computer is supporting everything 3D mode needs.
For more info [look here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements)

Answer (score 0):

The 'logical' answer would be to add `compiz --replace` to the startup programs. I had to answer for the people trying this that this not only didn't work for me, but **it made unity not to start** at all. I'm still looking for the answer as I need compiz working perfectly fine on startup.

Comment: I'm totally aware that I can just add that to startup applications, but my issue is that I want to use cinnamon and the upgrade just borked that installation. Cinnamon doesn't use compiz for compositing/window management.