# Compiz effects do not function on login, only after manual enabling

Tags: 12.04, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiz ( or even compositing in general) is not starting up when I login. Solution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129470/compiz-or-even-compositing-in-general-is-not-starting-up-when-i-login-soluti)

I have set the bottom left corner to window scale and the bottom right corner to show desktop. These effects do not work after login/boot. I have to open ccsm, remove the binding, click OK, reset the binding, click OK again and then it works. And then I have to do the same thing for the other corner. When I reboot the settings again won't work, although they are clearly activated and shown correctly in ccsm.

Everything worked fine under 11.10 so I don't know what to do. My computer is Asus 1215n with a fresh install of 12.04 64bit and bumblebee.

So far I tried putting the `compiz --replace` command in the startup applications, but while this worked once, it did not work afterwards anymore so I am back to square 1.

Comment: actually I just found a bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/986208
hopefully it will be fixed soon!

Comment: Exact duplicate - http://askubuntu.com/questions/129470/compiz-or-even-compositing-in-general-is-not-starting-up-when-i-login-soluti